# GET will not be transmitted

Tags: php, codeigniter, get

I have a problem with this GET.
I want to pass on three values (ygo, dane, 1) with a link to index, so that these values are entered in the respective WHERE.
But unfortunately there is no value on the page and I just don't know why.

IMG:
https://screenshots.firefox.com/g6qcToRn.../127.0.0.1

**Controller:**

```
public function index($slug) {
    $url = 'edition/index';
    $array = explode ('/',$url);
    $data['array'] = $array[0];
    $data['title'] = 'Edition Liste';
    $data['edition_listes'] = $this->Edition_model->edition_listess($slug);
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view($url, $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
public function edition($tcg,$id,$short) {
    $url = 'edition/edition';
    $array = explode ('/',$url);
    $data['array'] = $array[0];
    $data['get_edition'] = $this->Edition_model->get_edition($tcg,$id,$short);
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view($url, $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

**Model:**

```
public function edition_listess($slug) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('db_edition');
    $this->db->where('db_edition.tb_edition_tcg', $slug);
    $this->db->order_by('db_edition.tb_edition_kurzel', 'ASC');
    $this->db->order_by('db_edition.tb_edition_date', 'ASC');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
public function get_edition($tcg,$id,$short) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('db_edition');
    $this->db->where('db_edition.tb_edition_tcg', $tcg);
    $this->db->where('db_edition.tb_edition_id', $id);
    $this->db->or_where('db_edition.tb_edition_kurzel', $short);
    $this->db->order_by('db_edition.tb_edition_kurzel', 'ASC');
    $this->db->order_by('db_edition.tb_edition_date', 'ASC');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-10">
    <?php foreach ($edition_listes as $edition_liste): ?>
        <div class="list-group">
            <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>edition/edition/<?php echo $edition_liste['tb_edition_tcg'];?>/<?php if($edition_liste['tb_edition_kurzel'] > '') { echo $edition_liste['tb_edition_kurzel']; } else { echo $edition_liste['tb_edition_id']; } ?>" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-secondary">
                <div class="media">
                    <img class="media-object img-rounded img-responsive"  src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/assets/images/display.png" alt="placehold.it/350x250">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><?php echo $edition_liste['tb_edition_name'];?></h4>
                        <p class="list-group-item-text">
                            <b>SET ID: </b><?php if($edition_liste['tb_edition_kurzel']): echo $edition_liste['tb_edition_kurzel']; endif; ?></br>
                            <b>Kartenmenge: </b><?php echo $edition_liste['tb_edition_size'];?></br>
                            <b>Release: </b>00.00.0000
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 text-right">
                        <h5 class="colors">Pre-Release: <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i></button></h5>
                        <h5 class="colors">Pre-Release: <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></button></h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-1">
    </div>
</div>
```

**edition.php** (test page)

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo $slug; ?>
```

Comment: Welcome! The link to the image is not working. Also, please focus on your problem which seems to be "no value on the page" and describe this problem more in detail. For me, it's not clear what you mean with "no value on the page". What page?

Comment: On the test page (edition.php)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not passing the third argument to `edition($tcg,$id,$short)`. That likely means your model is using `null` for the value of `$short` in the call to `$this->db->or_where('db_edition.tb_edition_kurzel', $short);` so it is probably not returning any records.

Your code could be a lot easier to read. Here is code-snippet suggestion on how to create the link to the edition controller

```
...
<div class="list-group">
    <?php
    $tcg = $edition_liste['tb_edition_tcg'];

    if($edition_liste['tb_edition_kurzel'] !== '') // use a more reliable test for an empty string than > ''
    {
        $id = $edition_liste['tb_edition_kurzel'];
    }
    else
    {
        $id = $edition_liste['tb_edition_id'];
    }

    $short = 1;
    ?>
    <a href="<?= base_url("edition/edition/$tcg/$id/$short"); ?>" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-secondary">
...
```

In case you are not familiar with the syntax `<?=` is exactly the same as `<?php echo` - but with a lot less typing.

Now, a bonus suggestion. I'm not sure exactly why you are using this code

```
$url = 'edition/index';
```

There is a way to get the current controller and method without hard-coding it.

```
$url = $this->router->class . '/' . $this->router->method;
```

That way if you rename the controller or the method you don't have to change the hard-coded string. Yeah!

CodeIgniter does not document the router class, but the source code is in `/system/core/Router.php` and every controller will have an instance of the router class available as the property `$this->router`.